# Scala warning match may not be exhaustive while parsing

Tags: scala, parsing

```
  class ExprParser extends RegexParsers {
    val number = "[0-9]+".r
    def expr: Parser[Int] = term ~ rep(
      ("+" | "-") ~ term ^^ {
        case "+" ~ t => t
        case "-" ~ t => -t
      }) ^^ { case t ~ r => t + r.sum }
    def term: Parser[Int] = factor ~ (("*" ~ factor)*) ^^ {
      case f ~ r => f * r.map(_._2).product
    }
    def factor: Parser[Int] = number ^^ { _.toInt } | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"
  }
```

I get the following warning when compiling

```
warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: ~((x: String forSome x not in ("+", "-")), _)
      ("+" | "-") ~ term ^^ {
                            ^
one warning found
```

I heard that @unchecked annotation can help. But in this case where should I put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that with `("+" | "-")` you are creating a parser that accepts only two possible strings.  However when you map on the resulting parser to extract the value, the result you're going to extract will just be `String`.

In your pattern matching you only have cases for the strings "+" and "-", but the compiler has no way of knowing that those are the only possible strings that will show up, so it's telling you here that your match may not be exhaustive since it can't know any better.

You could use an unchecked annotation to suppress the warning, but there are much better, more idiomatic ways, to eliminate the issue.  One way to solve this is to replace those strings with some kind of structured type as soon as possible.  For example, create an ADT

```
sealed trait Operation
case object Plus extends Operation
case object Minus extends Operation

//then in your parser
("+" ^^^ Plus | "-" ^^^ Minus) ~ term ^^ {
  case PLus ~ t => t
  case Minus ~ t  => -t
}
```

Now it should be able to realize that the only possible cases are `Plus` and `Minus`

Answer (score 1):

Add a case to remove the warning

```
class ExprParser extends RegexParsers {
val number = "[0-9]+".r
def expr: Parser[Int] = term ~ rep(
("+" | "-") ~ term ^^ {
  case "+" ~ t => t
  case "-" ~ t => -t
  case _ ~ t => t
}) ^^ { case t ~ r => t + r.sum }
def term: Parser[Int] = factor ~ (("*" ~ factor)*) ^^ {
 case f ~ r => f * r.map(_._2).product
}
 def factor: Parser[Int] = number ^^ { _.toInt } | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"
}
```